# Combine multiple rows into 1 - Update table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to combine rows in my table;  dvsAIPGroupID’s:  8 & 73 are being combined into just 8. I want to sum the values for hedges, aiptotal, and value and group by the rest of the columns.

This Table
[image]

Becomes this:
[image]

I can take a 2 step approach.

- First, update the dvsgroup_id = 8 and dvsAIPGroup_Name = DOM
- Second, I need to group by and sum the Hedges, AIP Total, and Value.

I am not sure how to update the second step.

It will be a one-time change and below would be the select statement which includes all my fields.

```
SELECT GasYearName, GasYear,dvsAIPGroup_ID, dvsAIPGroup_Name, dvsInstrumentType_Descript,
       dvsRegion_ID,dvsRegion_Name, dvsSuperRegion_Name, sum (Hedges) AS Hedges, sum (AIPTotal) AS AIPTotal, sum (Value) AS Value, AsOfDate
FROM AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot
WHERE dvsAIPGroup_ID IN (860,1073)
AND AsOfDate >= '6/05/2020'
GROUP BY GasYearName, GasYear,dvsAIPGroup_ID, dvsAIPGroup_Name, dvsInstrumentType_Descript,
       dvsRegion_ID,dvsRegion_Name, dvsSuperRegion_Name, Hedges, AIPTotal, Value, AsOfDate
```

I created a set of sample data:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    select * from sysobjects where name='AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot' and xtype='U'
) CREATE TABLE AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot (
    [GasYearName] NVARCHAR(10),
    [GasYear] INT,
    [dvsAIPGroup_ID] INT,
    [dvsAIPGroup_Name] NVARCHAR(4),
    [dvsInstrumentType_Descript] NVARCHAR(2),
    [dvsRegion_ID] INT,
    [dvsRegion_Name] NVARCHAR(3),
    [dvsSuperRegion_Name] NVARCHAR(2),
    [Hedges] NVARCHAR(4),
    [AIPTotal] INT,
    [Value] INT,
    [AsOfDate] DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot VALUES
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-12,-12,'2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',0,0,'2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-11,-11,'2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''22/''23',2022,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-49,-49,'2020-06-05 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'28',-12,0,'2020-06-12 00:00:00'),
    (N'FY ''20/''21',2020,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',0,0,'2020-06-12 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-11,-11,'2020-06-12 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''22/''23',2022,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-49,-49,'2020-06-12 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'28',63,0,'2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',0,0,'2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-16,-16,'2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-11,-11,'2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''22/''23',2022,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'46',-49,-30,'2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',63,0,'2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''20/''21',2020,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',0,0,'2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,8,N'DOM ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-16,-16,'2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''21/''22',2021,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'NULL',-11,-11,'2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
    (N'GY ''22/''23',2022,73,N'ROC ',N'T ',3,N'NW ',N'W ',N'46',-49,-30,'2020-06-26 00:00:00');
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can work by small steps as you are already doing, once you have updated your rows, you can extract them into a temporary table. then delete the rows from the main table.
then group by your temp table and insert it into the main table

Comment: The question looks a little bit scary. Is there a way you could ask the same concept but using smaller sized data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Corrected one of your GasYearName (6th row has an 'F')
2. Change the type of the field Hedges to int.
   If you want to keep it as nvarchar, replace Hedges SUM line with:
   ,   Hedges      =   SUM(ISNULL(Hedges   , 0)*1)
3. I got rid of AsOfDate

Try this:

```
DECLARE @AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot TABLE 
    (
            [GasYearName]                   nvarchar(10)
        ,   [GasYear]                       int
        ,   [dvsAIPGroup_ID]                int
        ,   [dvsAIPGroup_Name]              nvarchar(4)
        ,   [dvsInstrumentType_Descript]    nvarchar(2)
        ,   [dvsRegion_ID]                  int
        ,   [dvsRegion_Name]                nvarchar(3)
        ,   [dvsSuperRegion_Name]           nvarchar(2)
        ,   [Hedges]                        int
        ,   [AIPTotal]                      int
        ,   [Value]                         int
        ,   [AsOfDate]                      datetime
    )
;
INSERT INTO @AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot VALUES
        (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -12,    -12,    '2020-06-05 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,     0,      0,    '2020-06-05 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -11,    -11,    '2020-06-05 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''22/''23',   2022,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -49,    -49,    '2020-06-05 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  28  ,   -12,      0,    '2020-06-12 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,     0,      0,    '2020-06-12 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -11,    -11,    '2020-06-12 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''22/''23',   2022,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -49,    -49,    '2020-06-12 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  28  ,    63,      0,    '2020-06-19 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,     0,      0,    '2020-06-19 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -16,    -16,    '2020-06-19 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -11,    -11,    '2020-06-19 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''22/''23',   2022,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  46  ,   -49,    -30,    '2020-06-19 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,    63,      0,    '2020-06-26 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''20/''21',   2020,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,     0,      0,    '2020-06-26 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,    8, N'DOM ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -16,    -16,    '2020-06-26 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''21/''22',   2021,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  NULL,   -11,    -11,    '2020-06-26 00:00:00')
    ,   (N'GY ''22/''23',   2022,   73, N'ROC ',    N'T ',  3,  N'NW ', N'W ',  46  ,   -49,    -30,    '2020-06-26 00:00:00')
;

SELECT 
            GasYearName
        ,   GasYear
        ,   dvsAIPGroup_ID
        ,   dvsAIPGroup_Name    
        ,   dvsInstrumentType_Descript       
        ,   dvsRegion_ID                    
        ,   dvsRegion_Name                  
        ,   dvsSuperRegion_Name
        ,   Hedges      =   SUM(ISNULL(Hedges   , 0))
        ,   AIPTotal    =   SUM(ISNULL(AIPTotal , 0))
        ,   Value       =   SUM(ISNULL(Value    , 0))
    --  ,   AsOfDate
        
FROM        @AIPBalance_WeeklySnapshot

WHERE   1=1
    --  AND dvsAIPGroup_ID  IN  (860,1073)
    --  AND AsOfDate        >=  '6/05/2020'
    
GROUP BY 
            GasYearName
        ,   GasYear
        ,   dvsAIPGroup_ID
        ,   dvsAIPGroup_Name
        ,   dvsInstrumentType_Descript
        ,   dvsRegion_ID
        ,   dvsRegion_Name
        ,   dvsSuperRegion_Name
    --  ,   AsOfDate
ORDER BY
            dvsAIPGroup_ID
        ,   GasYear
```